# How to correctly share a variable between multiple prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, prototype

So basically what i am trying to do which should be clear in my example is access a variable within a prototype across multiple functions inside that prototype. I am not sure how to correctly handle this so please provide example from the below code how to properly handle sharing variables.

I am using Phaser game states for my project and this is just a general example of my usage that i have thought. I am new to prototypes so still learning it.

```
var x = x || {};
var sharedVariable;
x.prototype = {
    function1: function() {
        console.log(sharedVariable);
    },
    function2: function() {
        console.log(sharedVariable);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `x.prototype`, then `x` should be a constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, please.

```js
function x(){
  this.sharedVariable = 1;
}

x.prototype = {
  function1: function(){
    console.log(this.sharedVariable++);
  },
  function2: function(){
    console.log(this.sharedVariable++);
  }
}

var y = new x();

y.function1(); //print 1
y.function2(); //print2
```